# What is a WLAN?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration

The reason I'm asking is that I'm setting up a guest network on my router to attach my new smart tv to.

I enabled the guest network and everything works fine.

However, the 'Guest WLAN' on this network is disabled. I thought WLAN meant 'a WiFi network', but the guest network is operational already.

What is the added benefit of turning on this `Guest WLAN` feature?

After enabling it asks if I want `access scenario` set to `External guest` or `Home guest`. Any idea?

**Router:** ZyXEL VMG8324-B10A

Comment: Without knowing the make and model of your router or access point, answering this question is difficult.

Comment: @DanielB Added the router to the post.

Comment: @Moab I know this. That's why I'm enabling the guest network and it works as intended. It's just that I don't know the benefit of turning on `Guest WLAN`.

Comment: @Moab In the first sentence, I'm saying I just set it up for the smart tv.

Comment: Wireless. It was working fine with my phone but can't connect with the tv. Will try to enable `Guest WLAN`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103462/discussion-between-yoeriboven-and-moab).

Comment: See page 82 of the users guide for home or external guest, I would use external for the TV>>>>>https://www.zyxel.com/support/SupportLandingSR.shtml?c=gb&l=en&kbid=M-01574&md=VMG8324-B10A